# how to hide loading image when data loaded

Tags: jquery

I want to hide processing image when data loading process is completed

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBtn").click(function(){
 $('.loader').show();
        $.post("search.php",
 {
     searchText : $('#search').val()
 },
 function( data ){
     $("#responseText").html(data);
 });
     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the always handler of the ajax promise hide the loader image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
    $('.loader').show();
    $.post("search.php", {
      searchText: $('#search').val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#responseText").html(data);
    }).always(function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
    });

  });
});
```

Don't do it in the success handler, because you might want to hide it in the case of error also.